# Angular/Bootstrap RFS is messing up the column grid

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5

I'm using the latest version of Bootstrap, Angular, and ngx-Bootstrap.  In one section of the HTML, it looks like Bootstrap's *row* child classes are being overwritten by _rfs.scss (see screenshot).  I am not using RFS and don't know how to get rid of it.  I'm importing the Bootstarp CSS in my SCSS, but I am not doing anything fancy. The HTML snippet below is using the *col-lg-3*, which is being set to *width: 100%*.

package.json:
 `... "@angular/animations": "^15.1.3", "@angular/common": "^15.1.3", "@angular/compiler": "^15.1.3", "@angular/core": "^15.1.3", "@angular/forms": "^15.1.3", "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.1.3", "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.1.3", "@angular/router": "^15.1.3", "@ng-select/ng-select": "^10.0.1", "bootstrap": "^5.2.3", "ngx-bootstrap": "^10.2.0", ...`

product-list.scss:
`@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";`

HTML snippet:
`<div class="container"> <div class="row"> <aside class="col-md-12 col-lg-3">`

[image: width being overwritten]

I've tried everything I can think of: different *col-* classes, different parent layers, and tuning off RFS with `$enable-rfs: false;`.  If I uncheck the *width: 100%*, it works as expected.  Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[_rfs.scss *is* Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/scss/vendor/_rfs.scss). Column styling is overridden by column classes or flex properties. The width property is inconsequential (or would be if you had followed  [the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/grid/#example) more carefully).

To clarify, since you didn't include `col` or `col-12` per the docs, no specific column width is applied other than the default mobile-first 100% width rule.

I suggest you revise to ask about the *problem* and not what you think is the cause. We'll help you fix up your markup.

FYI, you shouldn't be loading Bootstrap *and* Ngx-Bootstrap. You [only load the CSS for Bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-bootstrap), not the entire library.

Comment: I did include the column classes (see the HTML snippet above).  I'm using "col-md-12 col-lg-3".  As shown in the screenshot of the inspected CSS, the col-lg-3 is being overwritten by "row > *" from _rfs.scss.  The question is why and how to fix.

Comment: As I indicated, any column should have either `col` or `col-12` on it. This is the basic column class. Then you revise for larger breakpoints with the other classes. See also every column in the documentation I linked.

Comment: That is not a response to the problem. If you want to rely on the bootstrap grid to render 4 entries with col-md-6 to show up as 2 rows of 2 entries on desktop and on mobile as 4 rows of 1 entry, then you should only use `.col-md-6`, not `.col.col-md-6` or `.col-12.col-md-6`.
For the grid-system to work,  `col-md-6` etc. all define a specific width that *should* be applied if the breakpoint is not reached yet.
That this somehow breaks due to new css rules being thrown in from _rfs.scss is the fundamental issue and not addressed here.

Answer (score 0):

I had an identical problem to OP and also opened a question for it, that I [later found the answer to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76140962/angular-bootstrap-ngbootstrap-rfs-scss-width-rule-overriding-column-width-of/76142045#76142045).

In my case, the problem was in the way I imported the bootstrap.scss file into my component. Or rather, I used @import to import an scss.file, which by itself imported bootstrap.scss. That file caused RFS rules to appear.

More specifically, see if you have any bootstrap imports that look like this:

`@import '/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';`

Those may be problematic outside of styles.scss and maybe even then, though I can't tell you the reason as to why that is.

`@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';` has worked better for me so far.